# How to apply %% to a variable in a script with input parameter?

Tags: batch-file, dos

I asked a question yesterday about how to manage to get %% around a variable without getting the evaluation.
Well, the thing is, it does not work that way in my case...

I have a .bat file which gets an input parameter. Later on I want to use the value of this input parameter and put %...% around, like:

```
call script.bat testValue
```

script.bat:

```
 set inputPar=%1
 set newValue=%%inputPar%%
```

Now I get:

```
 echo %inputPar%
testValue
 echo %newValue%
%inputPar%
```

But I would like to get:

```
echo %newValue%
 %testValue%
```

Is that somehow possible?

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're getting those results is because `%%inputPar%%` is being treated as <kbd>%%</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>u</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>P</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>%%</kbd> and `%%` becomes a literal `%`.

You need:

```
first.cmd:
    @echo off
    call script.cmd testValue
script.cmd:
    @echo off
    set inputPar=%1
    set newValue=%%%inputPar%%%
    echo %inputPar% should be testValue
    echo %newValue% should be %%testValue%%
```

This gives you <kbd>%%</kbd><kbd>%inputPar%</kbd><kbd>%%</kbd> and, again, `%%` becomes a literal `%` with `%inputPar%` becoming `testValue`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

set inputPar=%1

set inputParDollar=%%%inputPar%%%

:: installDir is an already set environment variable

set installDirDollar=%%%installDir%%%

echo inputPar: %inputPar%

echo inputParDollar: %inputParDollar%

echo installDirDollar: %installDirDollar%

---

call script.bat testValue

inputPar: testValue

inputParDollar: %testValue%

installDirDollar: %D:\testenv%